# inserting directory address in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying something with file upload and sql lately, and I have this small problem. When I'm trying to insert this string to sql, the sql insert different value. Here is the text I'm trying to insert.

```
C:\xampp\tmp\phpCD2.tmp
```

and here is the text inserted in mysql

```
C:xampp    mpphpCD2.tmp
```

so from what I see the php/mysql remove all the '\' and convert the '\t' to a tab or spaces. I know it will be fix if I change the directory but what if I have some file starting with 't' so it will be remove, so How can I fix this. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name)
    {
        $name = $files['name'][$position];
        $tempName = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $type = $files['type'][$position];
        $size = $files['size'][$position];

        echo $tempName, '<br>';

        $insert = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (id, name, tempName, type, size) 
        VALUES ('', '$name', '$tempName', '$type', '$size') ";
        mysql_query($insert);
    }
```

Comment: We need to see your code...

Comment: edited. you can see the code

Comment: what is the data type of column for `C:xampp    mpphpCD2.tmp`

Comment: it was varchar and i put 255 as a lenght

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the string.

```
$tempName = mysql_escape_string($files['tmp_name'][$position]);
```